# What would the floor of 0.99999....

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I saw a post on r/learnmath about this, but I wanted to hear what you guys think.

If I think in terms of sequences, I believe that it would be equal to zero, since 0.9999...9 (with n '9's) would always be less than 1 and greater than 0 for all natural n and hence, the floor would be zero (making the limit as n goes to infinity 0). However, if we first evaluate what's inside, then we'd get the floor of 1, which is just 1.

I personally think the first 'method' yielding 0 is more consistent with the idea of sequences.

Comment: You’ve just proven that the floor function is discontinuous at $x=1$

Comment: So, you think that $\left\lfloor\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\frac1n\right\rfloor=0$, right?!

Comment: @AnotherUser yes, that was what I was thinking of, but Lee Mosher's answer has corrected me by clarifying that 0.999.... is not a sequence and hence, the floor is 1

Comment: @MartinR that was not my question, I already knew that it equals 1 because if we define it as the limit of a sequence to infinity, we simply obtain 1 because it's an infinite geometric series with starting term 0.9 and common ratio 0.1.

My question has already been answered, but thanks for taking the time to refer me to the link. I'll check it out

Comment: I notice that you have a lot of questions but none of them have an accepted answer. Please keep in mind: When people answer your question, you can choose to [accept one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: You ask for the floor of a single number (not a sequence). So , the first approach does not apply. And $0.\bar 9$ is a number , I disagree with the claim it is not.

Comment: I don't know what is 0.999999.... There is several notations for writing periodical decimal fractions, if you mean this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although (like *every* number) the number $0.9999\ldots = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{10^n}\right)$ is the limit of a sequence, the number $0.9999\ldots$ is not *itself* a sequence. It is a number. And it is equal to $1$. So its floor is $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean now.

Comment: Nitpicking, a "decimal number" isn't a number at all, but rather a *representation* of a number.  Now for the sake of uniqueness of that representation it must not finally end in a sequence of infinite-many nines.  Agree in this, and the (mathematical) world would be a (slightly) better one ...

Comment: Uniqueness is not all its cracked up to be.